# How can I set or change a user session time out in OpenAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, timeout, openam, forgerock

I currently have OpenAM Community edition version 14.5 running with OpenDJ as an LDAP. I do not have a web agent running against my application. Users have been complaining that they have been getting signed out of our application when idle. I was looking to change that setting that OpenAM seems to enforce. I see that in Configure -> Global Services -> Session -> Session Quotas , there is a parameter called "Read Timeout for Quota Constraint", would this be the parameter to change?

Answer (score 1):

OpenAM offers realm-based SSO session timeouts. You can register the 'Session Service' in your realm and set 'Max Session Timeout' and 'Max Session Idletimeout'.
'Session Quotas' is a different feature. It allows to specify how many SSO session a user is allowed to have in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found and enabled this 'session service' feature. Once I use this, will there be anything else that I need to focus on to get it to work with my current application?

Comment: It's application independent. This is only related to the SSO session on OpenAM side. When configured in 'notification mode' , the Agent gets a request from OpenAM when the SSO session times out or is administratively destroyed. Upon this request, the Agent flushes its SSO session cache. At least this was the original behavior. However nowadays there are multiple 'OpenAM Community editions' around, leveraging the work from iPlanet, Sun, ForgeRock, so you have to be very specific when asking questions.